# Display all YouTube videos based on tag

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way I can display all videos from YouTube with a specific tag? Can't find anything in the API about getting videos via tags.

Comment: what have you written? What language?

Comment: I have nothing written, but preferably Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can't display *all* videos, but you can do a search and get back around 1000 videos that match any given keyword. Here's the request URL you'd use for `baseball`:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com%2Fschemas%2F2007%2Fkeywords.cat%7Dbaseball